# Error in neo4j connectivity with Java

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, graph, neo4j

On adding the "dependencies" given above to my POM file I got the following error message.

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j-maven</id>
        <name>neo4j maven</name>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Code :

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * @author Shanal
 */
public class neo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Make sure Neo4j Driver is registered
        Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");

        // Connect
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/");

        // Querying
        try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("MATCH (n:User) RETURN n.name");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("n.name"));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Error :

```
run:

Starting the Apache HTTP client

Executing query: MATCH (n:User) RETURN n.name
with params {}
Starting the Apache HTTP client
errors-next-token = FIELD_NAME
null
Unexpected token END_ARRAY
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in neo4j-jdbc. It has been fixed now. Take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/issues/8). It matches exactly your case.

Answer (score -2):

You can't use JDBC with Neo4J.  Any references in your code to `java.sql.*` are incorrect.

Have a look at [this link](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html) for information on how to execute Cypher queries via Java.  The way your code is going about it is in the wrong direction here.

Comment: There is a JDBC driver for Neo4j: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc that works with issues via REST.
We have a template project with maven that works on GrapheneDB + Cloudbees, but can be adapted to other setups with any major changes: https://github.com/Judit/maven_neo4j_jbdc_sample

Comment: Frobber, is it worth deleting this answer?